# How to create xml string for each row of table?

Tags: sql-server

I have below sql table. I need to add a column `xmls` to my table such that the table looks like below.

```
CREATE TABLE employees(
      id          integer,
      name        VARCHAR(MAX),
      designation VARCHAR(MAX),
      manager     integer,
      hired_on    date,
      salary      integer,
      commission  float,
      dept        integer);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (1,'JOHNSON','ADMIN',6,'12-17-1990',18000,NULL,4);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (2,'HARDING','MANAGER',9,'02-02-1998',52000,300,3);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (3,'TAFT','SALES I',2,'01-02-1996',25000,500,3);
INSERT INTO employees VALUES (4,'HOOVER','SALES I',2,'04-02-1990',27000,NULL,3);
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id < 10;
```

The new column xmls should look like below(last column below), I know I can do it with the help of string utilities but cannot figure the simple yet effective and optimal solution.

[image]

This is what I tried but this does not give me the end tag `summary`.

```
SELECT (
SELECT id AS '@id',
designation AS '@type',
salary AS '@salary'
FROM employees b 
WHERE b.id = a.id
FOR XML PATH('summary'))
FROM employees a
```

[image]

Comment: `<summary />` and `<summary></summary>` are the same thing

Comment: I obviously know that,its the parser on which i don't have no control.

Comment: Which parser are you using that it actually makes a difference? No good parser should care.

Comment: Stating the obvious: if the "xml parser" does not parse either form, it's not an XML parser.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Strictly speaking, a self-closing tag `<summary />` and a full tag `<summary></summary>` have the same meaning in XML, so it shouldn't make a difference to you, or to any proper XML parser.

But if you want to force it to generate a full tag as opposed to a self-closing one, you can add an empty `text()` column:

```sql
SELECT (
    SELECT
      e.id AS [@id],
      e.designation AS [@type],
      e.salary AS [@salary],
      '' AS [text()]
    FOR XML PATH('summary')
  )
FROM employees e;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/XTYbYHtt)

You don't need to self-join in the subquery, you can refer to the outer columns directly. Note also that you should use `[]` to quote columns where necessary, not `''`.

---

Side note: you don't need to *store* this XML, you can create a view that brings it up when you query it.

Comment: `You don't need to self-join in the subquery, you can refer to the outer columns directly.` how??

Comment: As shown, there is no self-join. In subqueries you are allowed to refer to outer tables

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend **not** doing this at all.

All the data values in the XML are present in other fields within the record, which makes the XML a *derived* field.

General Rule: do not store Data that you can derive from other Data.

Instead, build the XML "on demand", in a Query, or in a View or in a calculated column.

At its simplest (albeit most likely to break if XML-meaningful characters aren't properly *escaped*):

```
select '<summary' 
  || ' id='\'' || id || '\''' 
  || ' type='\' || designation || '\''
  || ' salary='\' || salary || '\'' 
  || '\'/>' xml 
from table1
```

And, as others have said, `<summary></summary>` and `<summary/>` are completely equivalent in XML.  (To [X]HTML?  Perhaps not, but to XML itself?  Yes).

Comment: That's not valid T-SQL, and even in other systems that won't generate correct XML always (needs proper escaping). *build the XML "on demand"* that **is** what OP is doing already using `FOR XML`, it's just not working quite right.

Comment: My point is that the OP is trying to create and then /store/ the XML content in a new column.  That's a Bad Idea under any DBMS.